# Schema instance null during big query select when doing pagination

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using pagination and referring to this link
`https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#java`

My sample code looks like below

```
    public void readAggBatchBq() throws InterruptedException {
        BigQuery bq = bqConfig.bigQuery();

        TableId tableId = TableId.of(dataset, table);
        String query = "SELECT * from `test.historical_data`";
        QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
                QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
                        // save results into a table.
                        //.setDestinationTable(tableId)
                        //.setWriteDisposition(JobInfo.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)

                        .build();

        bq.query(queryConfig);

        TableResult results =
                bq.listTableData(tableId, BigQuery.TableDataListOption.pageSize(4));

        // First Page
        while(results.hasNextPage()) {
            Schema sch = results.getSchema();
            results
                    .getValues()
                    .forEach(row -> row.forEach(val -> System.out.printf("%s,\n", val.toString())));
            results = results.getNextPage();
        }
        results = results.getNextPage();
        System.out.println("Query pagination performed successfully.");
```

Schema is null when I read it from results. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no data in the table identified by `tableId`.

Try to uncomment:

```
//.setDestinationTable(tableId)
```

Comment: That is not related to this. It won't fix it. That is just used to tell google which temp table to use.